# winston custom transport formatted message

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, winston

I'm writing a little winston custom transport to send my logs to Kafka (existing transports are not updated or don't match my needs).

As explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#adding-custom-transports) for creating a new custom transport, I have a function called "log" which take 2 parameters, info and callback.
When I watch the content of info I see this :

```
{
  level: 'debug',
  message: '[Worker.ts - sleep] Sleeping 2929 ms',
  worker: 'default',
  timestamp: '2020-05-14 11:40:51.186',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'debug',
  [Symbol(message)]: '[2020-05-14 11:40:51.186][debug][default][Worker.ts - sleep] Sleeping 2929 ms'
}
```

So my question is, how can I access to [Symbol(message)] so I don't have to set a static formatting for my transport ?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should access the property via the `message` symbol thanks to [Symbol.for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for):

```js
info[Symbol.for('message')]
```